# Are humans a plague?

Tags: ecology

We have:

- Reached a population of 8 billion
- Doubled greenhouse gases
- Extincted numerous species
- Filled the ocean floor with waste
- Contaminated the soil with petroleum derivatives
- Contaminated aquifers

Could we be considered a plague? Do we have solution?

Comment: If you subscribe to the [Gaia Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia_hypothesis) it could be considered that humans are a pathogen & that global warming is the [fever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fever) necessary to control the pathogen. Life & the planet did quite well for [billions of years](https://www.science.org.au/curious/space-time/origins-life-earth) without humans. They don't need us, but we need them.

Comment: Sorry but this question will lead to opinion based answers, not facts.

Comment: *Closed yesterday by Jean-Marie Prival, trond hansen, Erik, Universal_learner, Nemesi.* What? You closed your own question? This doesn't happen often :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some (Or most ways) Yes. Pollution, Poaching, littering  and etc Has hurt Biodiversity, lots of Animals who went extinct because of Humans wouldnt be familiar to an Average person, [this link](https://alansfactoryoutlet.com/36-extinct-animals-lost-to-history-due-to-human-activity/) provides some insight into the animals that went extinct.

Humans are the most adaptable Animals in the world, this degree of Adaptability causing tremendous Population growth, Urbanization  and etc. [However there is a way to solve this](https://support.worldwildlife.org/site/Donation2?df_id=14597&14597.donation=form1&s_src=AWE1800OQ18695A01430RX&msclkid=0003702630561c979cc710edec6f9e63&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Brand&utm_term=wwf.com&utm_content=WorldWildlife.Org).

Denial and Politics has kept us doing this in the recent past, but yes, there is a way to fix this.